# Problemas com canvas dentro de uma WebView no react native

Tags: android, ios, react-native, canvas, webview

Por que ao alterar a altura > 100 e largura > 640 no canvas dentro de uma WebView no react native, nada mais e desenhando?

```
//funciona 
...
canvas.width  = 640;
canvas.height = 100;
ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
...

//não  funciona 
...
canvas.width  = 1024;
canvas.height = 768;
ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Consegui resolver alterando as dimensões ao final do carregamento do DOM, como no exemplo abaixo.

```
window.onload = () => {
   canvas.width  = 1024;
   canvas.height = 768;
   ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
   // ...
}
```